# How to define the data model without POJOS for received JSON format?

Tags: json, spring-boot, jsonschema, jsonserializer, maplist

I have to prepare the model for the response to be sent to model.

This is the sample JSON format that is received:

```
{
\\ rest of the model
"Model": {
    "name": "name_01",
    "description": "name_01",
    "features": {
      "name": "feature 01",
      "description": "feature 01"
    }
  }
\\ Rest of the model
}
```

Response to be sent to the fronEnd :

```
{
\\ rest of the model

"model_name":"name_01",
"feature_name":"feature_01"
}
\\ rest of the model
```

This is what I implemented so far:

Code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @JsonProperty("model")
    private void unpackNestedModel(Map<String,Object> model) {
        this.model_name = (String) model.get("name");
        Map<String, Object> model2 = (Map<String, Object>) model.get("features");
        this.feature_name = (String) model2.get("name");
    }
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: This is so confusing, you should probably use Map<String, Object> as you primary and keep adding nested objects which maybe another Map<String, Object> or List or string

Answer (score 2):

You can parse the result by `JSONObject`, but suggest to operate json result through POJO Object.

```
@Test
public void test02() {
    String receivedJson = "{\"Model\":{\"name\":\"name_01\",\"description\":\"name_01\",\"features\":{\"name\":\"feature 01\",\"description\":\"feature 01\"}}}";
    JSONObject receivedObj = JSONObject.parseObject(receivedJson);

    JSONObject model = (JSONObject) receivedObj.get("Model");
    JSONObject features = (JSONObject) model.get("features");

    JSONObject responseObj = new JSONObject();
    responseObj.put("model_name", model.getString("name"));
    responseObj.put("feature_name", features.getString("name"));

    System.out.println(responseObj);
    //output in console
    //{"model_name":"name_01","feature_name":"feature 01"}
}
```

Comment: I updated my question. Is there a better way for the way I did? Can I use map streams or something like that?

Comment: I think the best way is parsing the JSON string as a POJO, and then you can do what you want through getter method as normal.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid set and get method ? I have too many fields to set and get it.

Comment: @Holic I implemented JSON string as POJO

Comment: @bkumar If you develop via Intelij IDEA, try to press `alt+insert` to generate getter/setter. Or using `@Data` annotation to avoid get and set method, learning about lombok in here, https://projectlombok.org/

Comment: Sure! Thanks @Holinc

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Jackson and your request payload is like this:

```
{
  "Model": {
    "name": "name_01",
    "description": "name_01",
    "features": {
      "name": "feature 01",
      "description": "feature 01"
    }
  }
}
```

You could have the following classes to represent it:

```java
@Data
public class RequestData {

    @JsonProperty("Model")
    private Model model;
}
```

```java
@Data
public class Model {

    private String name;
    private String description;
    private Features features;
}
```

```java
@Data
public class Features {

    private String name;
    private String description;
}
```

If you enable the [`UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE) deserialization feature in your `ObjectMapper`, you could simply have:

```java
@Data
@JsonRootName("Model")
public class Model {

    private String name;
    private String description;
    private Features features;
}
```

```java
@Data
public class Features {

    private String name;
    private String description;
}
```

---

If your response payload is like:

```
{
  "model_name": "name_01",
  "feature_name": "feature_01"
}
```

You could have:

```java
@Data
public class ResponseData {

    @JsonProperty("model_name")
    private String modelName;

    @JsonProperty("feature_name")
    private String featureName;
}
```